# Concerns about APK version compatibility

Tags: android, unity

I'm making a game in Unity, and i want to know if I generate the apk in version 4.1 Jelly Bean he will run in newest versions of android?
Can anyone explain me better how the version works?

Comment: fyi I changed the title to better reflect your actual question (the bit about Unity really has nothing to do with it).

Comment: Android applications have a minSdkVersion and a targetSdkVersion. The targetSdkVersion should be the highest available (it is 22 in a random non-unity project I am working on, just to give you an idea) and the minSdkVersion is usually 8 or 10 which is usually the lowest android version that someone will have on super old android phones.

Comment: Ok, but in Unity i can only select one version, I want to know if I select this version my game will only work in the selected version?
Or have some way to configure in Unity the minSdkVersion and the targetSdkVersion?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set those within Unity, but you can set those in the manifest file with a line like <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: Lookup "unity android manifest" for information about working with that; I think this will get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241364/android-unity-plugin-manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it will work.**
if you set the game to 4.1 Jelly Bean it will work for the 4.1 and all the higher versions of android, here is a link for better explanation: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1395568821/m-1643858570